# OneNote 2013: Merging multiple pages or switching continuous viewing

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2013

I'm using OneNote 2013.

I have used the 'Print to OneNote' facility to import a bunch of textbooks that I'm working with.

At the time I didn't know about the advanced option to import large documents without paging them, so I now have sections with several hundred pages.  And a few shorter documents that are not paged too.

Ideally I'd like to be able to navigate through them as if they were a single document rather than several hundred discrete documents, and merge or regroup the pages by chapter.

I reason I can either do that by either:

1. Switching on some sort of continuous scrolling.
2. Merge the pages into a single page.

After a bit of hunting though, I have yet to find a continuous scrolling option or a way of merging pages.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switching to a scrolling view seems not to be an available option.  Which leaves merging the pages.

And in that regard, you have two options:

1. Copy/paste each page manually.
2. Buy a plugin to do it for you.

I went with the plugin (on account of I had several hundred pages to merge).

For anyone who stumbles across this page with the same problem then the plugin I used was: [OneNote Gem](http://www.onenotegem.com/) at a cost of US$28.

Answer (score 8):

In Onenote go to the FILE menu, then click OPTIONS, then on the left click ADVANCED, then scroll down on the right the second last check box is "Insert long printouts on multiple pages", untick it. problem solved.

Found this on: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/cf3c53b4-61bc-4352-b30e-60682f48e365/send-to-onenote-2013-splits-pages

Comment: Yes, I did that for future documents, but in this particular case, I had a several hundred page doc that already had a lot of edit notes and annotations added, so reimporting it would have resulted in a lot of lost work.  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new section and highlight all the pages you want to combine.  Right click and drag and hold on new section.  Once it opens up, let go of right click.  Now export to PDF and assemble.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest selecting each page you'd like to combine by pressing control and shift, then clicking each page simultaneously. Once all pages are selected click the share tab then select the E-mail page option. An email draft will be created consisting of all the pages selected combined.Just copy and paste wherever you'd like for editing.

Answer (score 0):

Chris, I don't know if you are still watching this post, since it's been over a year. If not, someone else may benefit from this post. I wonder if creating another section and moving any desired documents to that section and then exporting the entire section (digital) or printing the entire section (hard copy) vs page, would have solved your problem. It did for me. I'm using OneNote 2013. To do this, simply choose File > Export > and change options (on left of screen from page to section) and choose where to send it (i.e., pdf, webage, etc). NOTE: I did not need to group anything, after it was exported. Grouping by chapter could be done using the sections option in OneNote first as your delimiter, then printing each section as desired.

Another thought: An Adobe program may be more helpful. I used my old laptop for more flexibility (i.e., pdf package, single, multiple, etc). This current laptop does not have that program; therefore, it exports as a pdf reader file only. Any changes I would want to make specifically on this machine would have to be manipulated in OneNote first and then exported or printed as a complete product.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser, could you please try to clarify the steps. I would find current formulation difficult to follow. For example, exporting the section to what format? Why to print hard copy? What does *"(hard copy) vs page"* mean? Bullet points and logically organized paragraphs are your friends. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I simply create a new section select all pages needed, move or copy selected pages into my new section, go to file select export select format as current section then convert the section into a pdf.